# How do I add oAuth (DevDefined oAuth) to a C# windows forms project?

Tags: c#, oauth, television, justin.tv

I'm trying to make a desktop Justin.TV notifier with C#. I'm new to C# but I programmed in C++ and Java.

I've been google-ing and searching stackoverflow but haven't found a guide on how to add something like DevDefined to my project.

For Java, it was pretty simple adding oAuth. Just imported a couple of .js files. I've been stuck and frustrated searching. I wish I didn't have to ask such a simple question but help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sources are on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth). Download them, build the library and add the library in your C# project references.

There are code examples on the GitHub page or the [Google Code one](http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth).

Comment: Ohhhhh. I was downloading the files and folders being displayed on their Github page. Not the download and releases on the bottom.

I'm new to Github. Could you explain what the files displayed are vs. the ones being downloaded? Thanks Otiel!

Comment: @RogerLam: The files displayed (you can download them by clicking the **`ZIP`** button on the top) are the sources for the `.dll` file, the sources for examples and tests. The *download and releases* allows you to directly download the compiled `.dll` file.